# Kafka Consumer hangs intermittently

Tags: python, kafka-consumer-api

I have a process to load multiple Kafka topics into database.

It works and loads data but intermittently consumer hangs for 7-12 hours and then returns messages.

It only happens for 1 or 2 of the topics out of 11 in my list.

Since the topics have different characteristics (some are json, some are avro and some of them encrypted) I am using a consumer for each topic.

In the shortened code below;

1. I read the topics from topics_list json file
2. Create listeners object for each consumer/topic
3. Listen the topics and process data to load

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

class KafkaListener:
    def init(self,topic):

        self.topic_name = str(topic.get("topic_name")). # coming from topics_list json file
        self.offset = topic.get("offset", "earliest") # default earliest, would like to be able to control per topic
        self.timeout = topic.get("timeout", 24000) # default to 24,000 would like to be able to control per topic

        self.consumer = KafkaConsumer(
            group_id="group1",
            bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_server_address,
            auto_offset_reset=self.offset,
            value_deserializer=deserializer,
            consumer_timeout_ms=self.timeout,
        )
        self.consumer.subscribe([self.topic_name])

    def load(self):
        log(f"Started listening topic: {self.topic_name}")

        for message in self.consumer:
            < process the message >

        log(f"Load completed for topic: {self.topic_name}")

# read topics from file
with topics_list_file.open("r") as f_topics:
    topics_read = json.load(f_topics)

# build listeners for each topic
for topic in topics:
    listeners[topic] = KafkaListener(topics[topic])

# listen the topics, load data
while True:
    for listener in listeners:
        listener.load()
```

topics_list file

```
[
{
    "topic_name": "json_topic1",
    "message_type": "json"
},
{
    "topic_name": "avro_topic1",
    "message_type": "avro",
    "avro_schema": "avro_topic1_schema"
},
{
    "topic_name": "avro.topic2",
    "message_type": "avro",
    "avro_schema": "avro_topic2_schema"
},
{
    "topic_name": "json.topic2",
    "message_type": "json",
    "encrypted": "True"
}
]
```

excerpt from the latest log file

```
...
2020-04-23 13:03:46 Started listening topic: json_topic1
2020-04-23 20:10:09 Load completed for topic: json_topic1
...
```

In this example listener waited for about 7 hours before returning data.

How can I prevent this delay?

Any other approach I should use for this use case?

Update: added code for setting `topic names` and default values for `offset` and `timeout`

Comment: It seems you have left out some code.  I can't see how you set `self.offset`, `self.timeout`, or `self.topic`.  `self.timeout` is particularly important.  Can you show how you're setting those?

Comment: @RustyWidebottom added the code for the values you are asking. `Topic name` is coming from topics_list file. Setting defaults for `offset` and `timeout` but can be set from same file also.

Comment: If your first listener receives at least one message per 24 seconds, then the `for message in self.consumer:` loop will not end.  Any one of your listeners will block the others from ever running.  As a diagnostic, I would log a timestamp of each message as it arrives, to see if this is happening.  Secondly, use a much smaller timeout (1000ms or smaller) to give the other listeners a turn at consuming some messages.  Lastly, I would run each listener in a separate thread, so that if any one listener blocks, it won't be blocking the others.